# Create async function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have this module that wraps a call to an asynchronous method to watch for changes in the browser's geolocation `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`

```
var geo_value;

//Initialises the devices geolocation
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
    geo_value = position.coords.longitude + "," + position.coords.latitude;
});
```

Everytime the `watchPosition` method call fires, I store the value in a variable to provide me programmatic access to the `currentPosition` at any given time.

This all works fine, however I now want to expose this `currentPosition` via a custom async method that I am exporting from my module.

```
define(["global"], function (window) {

   var navigator = window.navigator;

   var geo_value;

   //Initialises the devices geolocation
   navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
       geo_value = position.coords.longitude + "," + position.coords.latitude;
   });


   return {
       currentPosition: function (callback) {
           setTimeout(function () {
               while (!geo_value) {
                   //keep looping until geo_value has been initially set by the watch position above
               }
               //geo_value has been set, execute callback
               callback(geo_value);
           }, 0);

       }
   };
});
```

I have made the `module` expose the `currentPosition`, which works if `geo_value` has already been set, but I also want it to wait asynchronously if `geo_value` hasn't been set and then execute the callback when the `watchPosition` finally sets a value for `geo_value`. I tried using the `setTimeout` function to attempt at making it asynchronous, but it didn't work.

Please any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Javascript is really a single-threaded event loop. Getting a feel for what exactly that means will take experience.

In this case, it means that your while loop will never terminate, because nothing else can happen while it's running.

One better way to do this is to call the callbacks you're getting as params to currentPosition when watchPosition is called.

```
define(["global"], function (window) {

   var navigator = window.navigator,
       geo_value,
       callbacks = [],


   //Initialises the devices geolocation
   navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
       geo_value = position.coords.longitude + "," + position.coords.latitude;

       // Update all callbacks with new value. 
       for (var i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
           callbacks[i](geo_value);
       }
   });


   return {
       onCurrentPosition: function (callback) {
           callbacks.push(callback)
       }
   };
});
```

Comment: The only issue is that you will not benefit from caching `geo_value` right now. If `geo_value` exists, you should call the callback right away AND push it in the callbacks. Also as far as I know, the OP was not interested in getting notified for every subsequent position changes, so once you have a position, you do not need to push any callbacks, just return the current one.

Comment: I would have marked this as the answer for the explanation, but @closure 's answer below with a few modifications is closer to what I want because I only need to execute the callback once. Your answer is best suited for a situation where one would want to subscribe to changes in geo_location.

Comment: @kooldave98 Actually this answer is closer, just change the name for `currentPosition` and stop pushing new callbacks once `geo_value` has a value, instead just call `callback(geo_value)` right away. @closure's solution will fail if `currentPosition` is called multiple times **before** `geo_value` has a value.

Comment: yeah, I think you're right. @closure 's will fail if called multiple times, and TBH, he didn't even give an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
define(["global"], function (window) {

   var navigator = window.navigator;

   var geo_value;
   var cb;

   //Initialises the devices geolocation
   navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
       geo_value = position.coords.longitude + "," + position.coords.latitude;
       if (cb) {
         cb(geo_value);
         cb = null;
       }
   });


   return {
       currentPosition: function (callback) {
        if (geo_value) {
            callback(geo_value);
        } else {
            cb = callback;
        }
   };
});
```

Comment: Works for a single callback, however what if I call `currentPosition` multiple times before `geo_value` has a value?

Answer (score 0):

This code below blocks other code to be executed as JavaScript only has one thread of execution:

```
while (!geo_value) {
    //keep looping until geo_value has been initially set by the watch position above
}
```

Instead try something like this:

```
currentPosition: function(callback) {
  if (geo_value) {
    callback(geo_value);
  } else {
    // try again 1 sec later
    setTimeout(this.currentPosition.bind(this, callback), 1000);
  }
}
```